# Why does 7za want to "replace the existing file" (unpacked folder structure wrong)?

Tags: 7-zip, archiving

Ok, so I want to unpack an archive using 7za; I'm in a MINGW64 shell of MSYS2 on Windows 10.

So, I first open a new, empty directory:

```
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp/
```

Let's make sure - is this directory really empty?

```
$ ls -la
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None 0 May 20 14:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None 0 May 20 14:23 ../
```

Indeed, it is. Let's get our archive:

```
$ wget https://sysprogs.com/getfile/1748/openocd-20211118.7z
...

Saving to: ‘openocd-20211118.7z’

openocd-20211118.7z           100%[=================================================>]   7.97M  10.4MB/s    in 0.8s

2022-05-20 14:24:32 (10.4 MB/s) - ‘openocd-20211118.7z’ saved [8359495/8359495]
```

Good... So, now - for purposes that will be revealed later - first let's inspect the archive inside, and see where we'd find the file `ftd2xx.lib`:

```
$ 7za l openocd-20211118.7z | grep ftd2xx.lib
2020-07-12 18:45:55 ....A        18652       489886  OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/drivers/FTDI CDM v2.08.28 Certified/amd64/ftd2xx.lib
2020-07-12 18:45:55 ....A        20418               OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/drivers/FTDI CDM v2.08.28 Certified/i386/ftd2xx.lib
2020-07-12 18:45:55 ....A      1014926               OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/drivers/FTDI CDM v2.08.28 Certified/Static/amd64/ftd2xx.lib
2020-07-12 18:45:55 ....A       904088               OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/drivers/FTDI CDM v2.08.28 Certified/Static/i386/ftd2xx.lib
```

Ok, so there are four of these files - but they are all in their separate directories; and also, it looks like the entire archive is "wrapped" in a "parent" folder, OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0 -- well, if that is the case, great, I can just unpack (as I do with `unzip`)?

```
$ 7za e openocd-20211118.7z

7-Zip (a) [64] 17.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.04 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700T CPU @ 2.90GHz (906E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 8359495 bytes (8164 KiB)

Extracting archive: openocd-20211118.7z
--
Path = openocd-20211118.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 8359495
Headers Size = 14117
Method = LZMA2:24 BCJ
Solid = +
Blocks = 2


Would you like to replace the existing file:
  Path:     ./ftd2xx.lib
  Size:     18652 bytes (19 KiB)
  Modified: 2020-07-12 18:45:55
with the file from archive:
  Path:     OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/drivers/FTDI CDM v2.08.28 Certified/i386/ftd2xx.lib
  Size:     20418 bytes (20 KiB)
  Modified: 2020-07-12 18:45:55
? (Y)es / (N)o / (A)lways / (S)kip all / A(u)to rename all / (Q)uit? q

Archives with Errors: 1



Break signaled
```

Wait, what? WHY would I want a file **overwritten**???

I started from an **empty** folder (confirmed earlier), and I can see in the listing, all these files are wrapped in a parent folder, which then contains individual folders ... Why on earth would there be a file that would get overwritten?

So, let's see the contents of the folder now:

```
$ ls
 amd64/       drivers/                        libdcc/                    Static/        xmc1xxx/
 arc/         erase_check/                    lm3s/                      ST-Link/       xscale/
 arm/         flash/                          loaders/                   stm32/         xsvf_tools/
 at91/        fm4/                            marvell/                   target/        driver.xml
 at91sam7x/   fpga/                           openocd/                   test/          ftd2xx.h
 atmel/       ft232r/                         OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/   ti/            ftd2xx.lib
 bin/         ftdi/                           OpenULINK/                 tools/         ftdibus.cat
 board/      'FTDI CDM v2.08.28 Certified'/   remote_bitbang/            transport/     ftdibus.inf
 checksum/    gti/                            rpc_examples/              watchdog/      ftdiport.cat
 chip/        i386/                           rtos-helpers/              WinUSB/        ftdiport.inf
 contrib/     infineon/                       scripts/                   WinUSB_Mini/   openocd-20211118.7z
 cpld/        interface/                      share/                     x64/
 cpu/         kinetis/                        spear/                     x86/
 debug/       kinetis_ke/                     st/                        xds110/
```

WHAT???! Where did all of this come from???

Weren't the contents of this archive supposed to be in a parent folder called `OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/`? Why am I seeing all these subfolders here, and not just a single `OpenOCD-20211118-0.11.0/` subfolder?

What is going on here - and how can I unpack a 7z archive, with the packaged folder structure intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to exec the command on this way:

```
7za x openocd-20211118.7z
```

`x` will ensure you have extracted files with full paths

Comment: Thanks a ton; as it is obvious, I don't really know 7za, and the first command I found online for extracting was `7za e ...`, and I thought, well, **e** must stand for "extract", so I'm probably good to go ... and I was not `:)` Thanks again!